# Sign In validation JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, validation, servlets, scriptlet

I'm developing a website that requires my validation of the sign in page.

For that I created text fields on the sign in form.

and validated them with my database using scriptlets.

```
<!--<form method="post" action="#">
             <h1>SIGN IN</h1>

 Email id:<input class="s_text" type="text" placeholder="Email id" name="si_1">

Password:<input class="s_text" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="si_2">

 <input type="submit" value="Sign In" name="si_3" id="sub_si">
         </form>-->
```

In scriptlet, I checked for the entered username and password in the database.

I want to add javascript event to the 'if else' condition in the scriptlet i.e. if the username from the database is empty, it show perform certain events and if not(else), it should perform some other events.

Any way to do so??

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking--scriptlets are executed on the server. JavaScript is executed on the client. What are you trying to do, and where, specifically, do you want to do it, noting that you can't arbitrarily mix client/server side operations without some form of communication, e.g., Ajax.

Comment: I am basically accessing creating a sign in form. So on the basis of the username and password entered by the user, I access other details of the user. I want that if the entered username or password does not match with the entries in my database, a javascript event...say an alert message should be executed. So, all I want is to include javascript in my scriptlet if/else using jsp.
Also, I don't know AJAX coding

Comment: You're confusing Java and Javascript. As Dave said, they execute at completely different times.  As for Ajax, you need to learn it. Pretty much everything uses Ajax nowdays. Ajax is also not really "coding" per se (i.e. not a new language): its just a concept, of doing a http call via javascript to call to a serverside page.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. Basically I wanted to do the stuff that every login id in any website does. To show wrong user or password message after matching the uid and pwd in the database. So if AJAX is the solution for that. I will learn it asap.